# Why doesn't this USB PCB layout work?

Tags: pcb, usb, impedance, layout

I am in the middle of making a small USB & LAN pass through PCB (a small add-on PCB for a larger project.)

I have some problems getting it to work properly. It is quite simple - it takes a USB signal from one connector to another, and that is that.

I know USB needs 90Ohm differential impedance (+-15%.)

The layout looks like this where the 2 highlighted lines are the USB data lines:

[image][image]

The PCB is a 0.8mm board, and for getting 90 ohms I have the differential trace to be 0.8mm wide with 0.2mm space - that gives me 83.605 ohms which is well within the 15% tolerance.

What can else be a problem with the layout? I kept the track on the bottom side of the PCB to avoid unwanted stubs on the connector.

Comment: Your ground, on the top layer has some discontinuities (asymmetry) near the uab connector. But even in this case I wouldn't worry too much, it's probably good enough for usb 2.0

Comment: Well, I have some problem, that when I use this, my device will detect the USB for a short while, and then disconnect -

Comment: I'm not sure why some are saying the USB D+/D- are swapped. Those are clearly two different connectors. That leads me to believe one is USB-A and the other is USB-B per the standard. Which means the D+ and D- are correct.
Did you find a solution? If so please post it here because this is a good question.

Answer (score 6):

I suspect that the way you have wired it from one connector to the other hasn't taken into account that you need to swap D+ and D- over i.e. you have inadvertently inverted the data. You may also need to do this for ground and Vcc.

It's impossible to be more certain given that you haven't shown a schematic.

Comment: My first thought as well, though the bottom looks more like a header than a connector - hard to tell either way

Comment: Well, the schematic is quiet simple - http://oi65.tinypic.com/2vte05y.jpg    It uses a internal to external USB connector like this: http://cpc.farnell.com/akasa/exusbie-40/lead-internal-external-usb-40cm/dp/CS20507  Right now if i try to use it as it is Well, I have some problem, that when I use this, my device will detect the USB for a short while, and then disconnect -

Comment: There are four pins connecting to four more pins and they transport GND, +V, -D and +D. I believe you have highlighted -D and +D. Please either properly identify them on your schematic or just swap over -D and +D and see if it works.